# Get network drive letter by name in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, network-drive

I'd like to remove network drives from the system using a PowerShell script.

I need to find the drive by name, as the command `$net.RemoveNetworkDrive('P:',1)` needs the driveletter.

Is there a command to find the network drive letter in PowerShell?

My script:

```
$Drive = "\\192.168.2.117\Blabla"
echo $Drive
cls
    if (((New-Object -Com WScript.Network).EnumNetworkDrives() | Where-Object {$_ -eq $Drive})) 
    {
       echo 'found Drive'
       #$net = $(New-Object -comobject WScript.Network)
       #$net.RemoveNetworkDrive('P:',1)
    } 
    else
    {
        echo 'Drive not there'
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try the following method for getting the drive information:

```psh
$Drive = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_mappedLogicalDisk `
         -filter "ProviderName='\\\\192.168.2.117\\Blabla'"
$Drive.Name
```

`$Drive.Name` would become the drive letter which should allow you to the do the following:

```psh
$net = $(New-Object -comobject WScript.Network)
$net.RemoveNetworkDrive($Drive.Name,$true)
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using `Get-PSDrive` instead of a COM Object.

Following code should work:

```
#get drive by root (note that we use "displayroot" for the comparison, "root" contains the driveletter)
Get-PSDrive | where {$_.DisplayRoot -eq "\\192.168.2.117\BlaBla"} | Remove-PSDrive
```

Or in Case you have to use the ComObject to remove the drive you can do the following:

```
$driveletter = (Get-PSDrive | where {$_.DisplayRoot -eq "\\192.168.2.117\BlaBla"}).root
$net.RemoveNetworkDrive($driveletter,$True)
```

Answer (score -1):

the **actual** solution is a combination of `Win32_LogicalDisk` and your PS cmdlet :

```
$net = $(New-Object -comobject WScript.Network)

foreach($driveLetter in Get-WMIObject -query "Select * From Win32_LogicalDisk Where DriveType = 4" | Select-Object DeviceID)
{
    #$net.RemoveNetworkDrive($driveLetter, $True)
    echo $driveLetter
}
```

This will remove networkdrives only and does not need any weird UNC path or something.

*Btw : dont use `1` where a `boolean` is expected, that paradigm will break your scripts one day ... its what professionals call "bad code"*

Comment: you notice that your script will delete every mounted network drive if there are multiple?

Comment: really? op is saying he has to find the drive by name so i would think he doesnt just want to delete everything

Comment: i think hes quite able to write an additional `if` himself. Alternatively, he can filter just like he already did in his question.

Comment: just saying ^^ btw `true` will be an unexpected token thus causing an error, it should be `$True`